# Too large JS-file generated

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart2js

I have this code:

```dart
// main.dart
import "package:angular/angular.dart";
main () => ngBootstrap();
```

I make `dart2js --minify --out=main.dart.js main.dart`

Then i have *main.dart.js* with size **2.6 MiB (2,744,320 bytes)**.
It is not normal. What i'm doing wrong?

Is angular.dart usable for production at this stage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212131/ question/answers have relevant information related to this question too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@media-slave24

Maybe this will be helpful for You:
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=14686

It's reported on dart bug tracking system. Some people using mirrors got 760kb. So it's definitely a bug.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me, i declared `@MirrorsUsed` and now main.dart.js is _670.6 KiB (686,736 bytes)_. But HOW it works? Official documentation says nothing useful for this.

Comment: @media-slave24 https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_mirrors/MirrorsUsed.html
and https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_mirrors.html

It's not stable API so it can be changed in future. I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: @media-slave24 670KiB is **17** times bigger than angular.min.js. Are you really considering embedding 670KB of javascript in a webpage? I do not understand why they do not mention anything about this problem on angulardart.org. (By the way, [https://angulardart.org/demo/] loads 2MB of javascript...).

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE (Jan '14): AngularDart 0.9.5 now includes a standard MirrorsUsed list.  To finalize it and trigger Dart's tree-shaking optimizations, you need to add a MirrorsUsed to your program

- listing all the classes you introduce.
- `override: '*'` to finalize the MirrorsUsed.

Since helloworld has no new classes, say:

```dart
@MirrorsUsed(override: '*')
import 'dart:mirrors';
```

[See Github for the complete helloworld program](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/demo/helloworld/helloworld.dart)

The key is to include a @MirrorsUsed annotation in your Dart file.  Pavel's link to the AngularDart tutorial is an excellent resource.

To actually answer your question:  Yes, AngularDart can be used in production but be aware that it is in "beta" release right now.  We expect many breaking API changes!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at angular.dart.tutorial Chapter 7 about deployment. It has a section on managing compiled code size:

https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/tree/master/Chapter_07