# Compiled AngularDart fails with error in dynamic_injector

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart2js, dart-mirrors

I have been trying to make AngularDart work but I always get exceptions for undefined objects.

```dart
@MirrorsUsed(
targets: const [
    'angular.core',
    'angular.core.dom',
    'angular.core.parser',
    'angular.routing',
    'angular.core.zone',
    'di.di',
    'di.dynamic_injector',
    NodeTreeSanitizer,
    DynamicParser,
    DynamicParserBackend,
    Injector
],
metaTargets: const [
    NgInjectableService,
    NgComponent,
    NgDirective,
    NgController,
    NgFilter,
    NgAttr,
    NgOneWay,
    NgOneWayOneTime,
    NgTwoWay,
    NgCallback,
    NgZone
],
override: '*'
)
import 'dart:mirrors';
```

And compiled javascript showing error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get$parameters' of undefined dynamic_injector.dart:42
DynamicInjector.newInstanceOf$4 dynamic_injector.dart:42
```

When I'm removing MirrorsUsed2 there is no errors, but compiled file is large.

Comment: Which version of AngularDart are you using?  And which version of the Dart SDK?

Comment: All latest. AngularDart >=0.9.4

Comment: At very least we are making the MirrorsUsed situation much simpler in 0.9.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding these helped for me

```dart
    'angular.filter',
    'angular.perf',
    'perf_api',
```

and instead of `angular.core.parser`

```dart
    'angular.core.parser.dynamic_parser'
    'angular.core.parser.lexer'
```

I also added all my own libraries.

See also https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=14686

Comment: Added those as well, but it doesn't helped. I have the same issue. My own libraries are not using Mirrors.

Comment: Mine neither, but I read this tip somewhere. I haven't tried if it's is really necessary. I guess the problem is that Angular has to reflect on your classes to do dependency injection and to make use of the annotations. And Angular can't cover you classes with @MirrorsUsesd, can it?

Comment: Have you tried to build with `pub build --mode=debug` maybe it gives a better error message (e.g. what newInstanceOf$4 meight be)

Comment: Thank you very much! It now works. dynamic_parser and lexer helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I found Dart-AngularJS when compiled not to run, even the simplest example.  I reinstalled my dart sdk to the latest stable version and the errors disappeared.  Could you see if this works?  Please see [related issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/375) on github project.